# Efficient Evaluation of the Expression

Tags: algorithms, contest-math, generating-functions, computational-complexity

I have stumbled upon this problem and couldn't really get to an efficient approach :

> **Problem:** 
> We have an array $P$ having $N$ elements denoted by $P_i$. Our task is to find the value of the below expression.
>
> $$X=\sum_{j=1}^k \prod_{i=1}^N(P_i-j)$$
> where $k$ is the minimum element in the array. We have to return the value of X modulo $10^9+7$.
>
> **Constraints**:
>
> $1 \le P_i \lt 10^9+7$ 
> $ 1 \le N \le 10^5 $

The only solution that I have been able to come up with is a brute force approach of complexity $O(N\times K)$ where $K$ is the minimum element in the array. I think maybe something like FFT or generating functions could be used but I couldn't understand how.

Any sort of help is appreciated!!

Comment: A naive question: why is not brute-force O(N x k)?

Comment: @Damien yes, you are right!. Updated . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $ f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^N (-1)( x - P_i) \sum_{i=0}^N a_i x^i$.

We want to calculate $ \sum_{x=1}^k f(x),$ which is a lot easier to do termwise with a change of variable, namely:

$$ = \sum_{x=1}^k \sum_{i=0}^N a_i x^i = \sum_{i=0}^N \left( a_i \sum_{x=1}^k x^i\right), $$

This is already quite a big simplification.
Note that $ \sum_{x=1}^k x^i$ could be further simplified via [Faulbaher's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: Thanks for such an interesting approach. I didn't know about Faulbaher's formula and using NTT and the formula, it did actually reduced the complexity to $N^2 + N(logN)^2$ . Still it wouldn't fit in Time limit. Are you aware of any fast way to compute Faulbaher's formula ?